# Deploy Flask service to Azure

Tags: python, azure, flask

I am trying to deploy a Flask App + React to Azure. I already created a Web-App on Azure but I am struggling to deploy my code.

Before, let me tell you things I cannot do:

- Using Docker
- Using Git

After this restrictions all the tutorials I found including the official MS documentation doesnt help me too much.

What I did so far is upload the code as zip as described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-zip

Anyway could somebody tell me the best practice and link me to some tutorials?

Comment: Hi,any updates now?

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?Any progress now?

Answer (score 1):

You could refer to my work steps and try to deploy your web app. As you found in the [Managing Python on Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-on-azure-app-service), Azure App Service provide you with a site extension. You could install packages on KUDU console.

Step 1 : Create Azure web app and add Extensions (here is Python 3.6.1 x64)

[image]

Step 2 : Publish your Flask project and add the `web.config`.

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="<Your Project Name>.app"/>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot"/>
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\Python361x64\python.exe|D:\home\Python361x64\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Step 3: Switch to the [Kudu CMD](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) (navigate to url your-app-name.scm.azurewebapp) and commands `cd Python361x64` and `touch get-pip.py` and copy the content of the url `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` into the `get-pip.py` via Edit button, then run `python get-pip.py` to install the pip tool.

[image]

Step 4 : Install any packages you need via `python -m pip install pyodbc`

[image]